# How to show that the limit of a function does not exist, while $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ do?

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf

It does seem like a very simple question, but I don't see how to do it properly.

How can we show that the limit of

## $$3^{\lfloor\frac{-\log(j)}{\log(2)}\rfloor}j^{\frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}}$$

as $j\rightarrow\infty$does not exist, while $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ exist and are equal to $1$ and $\frac{1}{3}$?

I can see it intuitively but don't see how to prove it. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: If the limit exists, then $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ must be equal.

Comment: I don't know how to prove that $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are what they are, so that is where I'm stuck

Comment: To be able to see it, you can interpret these liminf/limsup as : for $N$ as big as I want, I can find $n \geq N$ such that $u_n$ is arbitrary close to liminf (or limsup) (show it from the definition). So if $u_n$ would have a limit $l$, for $n$ big enough, you must have $u_n$ arbitrary close to $l$,limsup and liminf at the same time. Since the three can't be equal ($liminf \neq limsup$), there is a contradiction (it's the same idea as in the proof of the unicity of the limit)

Comment: Should the $k$ in $3^{\lfloor\frac{-\log(k)}{\log(2)}\rfloor}j^{\frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}}$ be a $j$?

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry typo :)

Comment: "I don't know how to prove that lim sup and lim inf are what they are, so that is where I'm stuck." Then change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every term of the sequence is in $(\frac13,1]$ since $x-1\lt\lfloor x\rfloor\leqslant x$ for every $x$. If $j=2^n$, the result is $1$. If $j=2^n+1$, the result is $\frac13\,\left(1+\frac1{2^n}\right)$. Hence the limsup is $1$ and the liminf is $\frac13$.